Reading values from 'Google form' is undefined
I wrote a code in App Script and connected it to a form on the Google Forum
Now the problem is that I can't read the data from the fields in any way.
I keep getting 'undefined' errors
Like: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'values')
If I fill in fixed values ​​- then it works great!!
function onSubmit(e) {
  var responses = e.values; // מערך של התגובות של המשתמש
  var emailAddress = responses[1]; // כתובת הדואר האלקטרוני
  var weddingDate = responses[2]; // תאריך החתונה
  var coupleName = responses[3]; // שמות החתן והכלה

  // בדיקה שכל השדות קיימים
  if (!emailAddress || !weddingDate || !coupleName) {
    Logger.log('Error: One or more fields are missing.');
    return;
  }

  // בניית ה-URL עם הפרמטרים
  var appUrl = `https://wedding-coundown-for-free-use.web.app?weddingDate=${encodeURIComponent(weddingDate)}&coupleName=${encodeURIComponent(coupleName)}`;

  // שליחת הנתונים לאפליקציה באמצעות קריאת URL
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(appUrl);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

  // פונקציה לשליחת אימייל עם הלינק לאפליקציה
  function sendEmailWithAppLink(emailAddress, appUrl) {
    var subject = 'לינק לאפליקציית ספירת הגומר ⏳';
    var message = `הנה הלינק לאפליקציה: ${appUrl}`;

    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }

  // שליחת האימייל עם הקישור לאפליקציה לכתובת האימייל של המשתמש
  sendEmailWithAppLink(emailAddress, appUrl);

  // שמירת הנתונים בלוג
  Logger.log(`Data sent to app: ${weddingDate}, ${coupleName}`);
}


The code should send an email to the address entered in the form with a link.
